# What is so special about the least norm solution in case of an undetermined system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, least-squares

In particular this is the go to approach in case of solving a least squares problem that lacks a unique solution, how does being the closest point to the origin among all the solutions make it any better than the others?

Comment: What do you mean by "closest point to the origin"? Do you mean the solution vector which is the sparsest?

Comment: The solutions of an underdetermined system of equations represent some sort of a hyperplane ( a straight line in case of two equations), the least norm solution looks for the point with the least norm on the hypersurface (i.e. the closest to the origin), but what's so special about that point in real applications?

Comment: Again, considering you mean the sparsest solution, i.e. the solution vector with the least non-zero components, this structure is desirable since it represents a prior knowledge we have on the problem. Concretely, in this era we might have a high-dimensional data, however most features will be irrelevant, thus leading to an estimator that will have high variance which doesn't generalize well. In signal processing sparse solutions can represent some physical meaning (But I'm not an expert on that). You can read more on [sparse approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_approximation)